# déja-dup not doing daily backup with suspend instead of reboot

Tags: suspend, backup, deja-dup

instead of shutting down my and rebooting my machine I suspend and wake it up every time I use it.

This however seems to break the déja-dup backup schedule which I have configured to be run daily.

The settings screen shows "Last backup X days ago" and "Next backup is today", all buttons are grayed-out.
It keeps this way without doing backups. When I reboot, a fresh backup is made.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the backups scheduled to run while your computer is suspended? That won't work.

Comment: Well…the schedule is set to "daily" so I expected déja-dup to run as soon as I wake up my computer.